# Passing data object via intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to pass an Object from one activity to another via intent. but i get this error

> New hash 0 is before end of array hash 3552645 at index 1 key null

activity 1 :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, activity2.class); 
intent.putExtra("mission", mission); 
intent.putExtra("task", task); 
startActivity(intent);
```

activity 2:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
mission = intent.getParcelableExtra("mission"); 
task = intent.getParcelableExtra("task");
```

here is my Log:

> New hash 0 is before end of array hash 3552645 at index 1 key null
>                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: here
>                                                                      at android.util.ArrayMap.append(ArrayMap.java:521)
>                                                                      at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2618)
>                                                                      at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
>                                                                      at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:786)
>                                                                      at android.content.Intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.java:6223)
>                                                                      at com.iperiatech.sams.mvp.Missions.TaskDetailActivity.onCreate(TaskDetailActivity.java:82)
>                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6877)
>                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3208)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3351)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1796)
>                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7230)
>                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

Comment: Is your object Parcelable?

Comment: Yes it's parcelable

Comment: I assume your problem is that your `parcel` and `unparcel` methods aren't consistent. Please post those methods and we can have a look. Or you can look at them yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity1.this, activity2.class);
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args .putSerializable("mission",(Serializable) mission); 
args.putSerializable("task",(Serializable) task); 
intent.putExtra("DATA", args);
startActivity(intent);
```

and receive like this

```
  Intent myIntent = getIntent();
  Bundle myBundle = myIntent.getBundleExtra("DATA");

  if (myBundle != null) {
      mission = myBundle.getSerializable("mission"); 
      task = myBundle.getSerializable("task");

  }
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement Parcelable which is more related to Android than Serializable, Do your solution works the same  using Parcelable as Serializable.